# Take database backup of a SQL server 2012 from local SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2012 installation that has some issues with SQL Server Agent because of which I cannot schedule a job or a maintenance plan to take backup.

What I am trying to do is to create a SQL Server job on SQL Server 2008 R2 and take backup of the SQL Server 2012 databases. Can someone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616764/sql-database-automatic-back-up

Comment: http://sqlbak.com/blog/scheduling-backups/

Comment: Why not fix the issue with SQL Server Agent?

Comment: What issues do you have with your SQL Server 2012 -agent? The service/permissions structures has changed in SQL Server 2012 since previous versions if that helps you?

Answer (score 6):

You should fix the SQL agent first.

as a temporary workaround, you can use SQLCMD and schedule it using windows scheduler for doing backups.

no need to spawn a job from different server and do the backup on another server.